# codeStyleSettings.xml always modified by Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

Using Android Studio 1.3.2, the .idea/codeStyleSettings.xml is constantly modified to add a section for `<Objective-C-extensions>...</Objective-C-extensions\>`. These changes are despite no Objective-C code existing within the project. After many attempts, I have been unable to revert these changes - they keep coming back every time Android Studio is opened.

Where are these changes coming from and how can I avoid Android Studio constantly restoring the modifications?

```
<Objective-C-extensions>
  <option name="GENERATE_INSTANCE_VARIABLES_FOR_PROPERTIES" value="ASK" />
  <option name="RELEASE_STYLE" value="IVAR" />
  <option name="TYPE_QUALIFIERS_PLACEMENT" value="BEFORE" />
  <file>
    <option name="com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.util.OCDeclarationKind" value="Import" />
    <option name="com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.util.OCDeclarationKind" value="Macro" />
    <option name="com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.util.OCDeclarationKind" value="Typedef" />
    <option name="com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.util.OCDeclarationKind" value="Enum" />
    <option name="com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.util.OCDeclarationKind" value="Constant" />
    <option name="com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.util.OCDeclarationKind" value="Global" />
    <option name="com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.util.OCDeclarationKind" value="Struct" />
    <option name="com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.util.OCDeclarationKind" value="FunctionPredecl" />
    <option name="com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.util.OCDeclarationKind" value="Function" />
  </file>
  <class>
    <option name="com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.util.OCDeclarationKind" value="Property" />
    <option name="com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.util.OCDeclarationKind" value="Synthesize" />
    <option name="com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.util.OCDeclarationKind" value="InitMethod" />
    <option name="com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.util.OCDeclarationKind" value="StaticMethod" />
    <option name="com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.util.OCDeclarationKind" value="InstanceMethod" />
    <option name="com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.util.OCDeclarationKind" value="DeallocMethod" />
  </class>
  <extensions>
    <pair source="cpp" header="h" />
    <pair source="c" header="h" />
  </extensions>
</Objective-C-extensions>
```

Comment: Yes, this is irritating.  In terms of not adding this change to a git repo, I've got a pre-commit hook in .git/hooks to reset this file before committing, but it's not an ideal solution.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `<Objective-C-extensions>` Section is added by the Android NDK Support Plugin. Which was added in 1.3 and is activated by default.

If you have activated this plugin it adds the Section to your codeStyleSettings.xml. Otherwise it will be removed.

Comment: Can you revert the behaviour by disabling the plugin?

Comment: @brunobowden yes, if you disable the plugin the section will be deleted by android studio

Comment: I've confirmed that it works. Thanks @devtribe, that's fixed a big pain point for me. I never would've guessed it was the Android NDK Support plugin.

Comment: To disable the plugin: Settings, Plugins, clear check by Android NDK Support, OK, restart Android Studio.

Comment: Can't disable the plugin in AS 3.3 because "Android APK Support" plugin depends on it. AS 3.4 Beta 3 has the other problem - it removes these entries whatever you do. So either stay on AS 3.4 or stay on older. If you have to work with both you may have to follow @ScottFeinstein's answer.

Answer (score 5):

Ran into this exact problem, which hampered process since codeStyleSettings.xml was a version controlled file.  Solved it (on my Windows machine if that makes a difference) with the low-tech solution of marking the file as read only.  Android Studio complained about it the first time after making that change, but I prevented it from unsetting read-only and things worked fine after that.

Comment: Deserves more upvote. Same situation here, solved the problem, thanks!

Comment: Won't this cause problems when the file is modified by another team member?