# Project.xml file automatically gets edited and staged for commit in android studio after update

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github, android-studio-3.0

After updating Android Studio to 3.6.1, the following lines get added in Project.xml in .idea folder.

```
<AndroidXmlCodeStyleSettings>
  <option name="ARRANGEMENT_SETTINGS_MIGRATED_TO_191" value="true" />
</AndroidXmlCodeStyleSettings>
```

This file was previously added to git and pushed to GitHub so locally adding to untrack is also not helping. Upon doing so, it is staging it as a new file during the next time I click commit option in VCS tab.

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32838535/codestylesettings-xml-always-modified-by-android-studio) that it might be due to the NDK support plugin but even disabling it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

You just need the remove this file from git. 
Use:

```
git rm --cached <file>
```

and its no longer be tracked by git.

Comment: As I have mentioned this already that doing this is even not helping.

Comment: Do you have a line for `Project.xml` in your `.gitignore` file?

Comment: No, this file is being tracked so it is not added.

Comment: So add it add the file will be ignored.

Comment: No, I don't want it to be ignored because it is there in the remote repo I am contributing to. The problem is why is the above few lines being added after every build.

Answer (score 0):

Since Android Studio always changes the Project.xml file, just try ignore that. If  you want to commit or pull, just do a `git checkout Project.xml` and commit/pull afterwards, just keep in mind to not click into the Project.xml file or it will be changed again